# Where do i need to set karate.config.dir to run my tests in multiple environments

Tags: dsl, karate

My current config file looks something like this:

```
function() {

  var env = karate.env;
  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
  karate.configure('ssl', true);

  if (!env) {
      env = 'dev';
  }

  var config = {
      env: env,
      internalGateway: 'https://gateway.com.au',
      externalGateway: 'https://gateway.com.au',
      GatewayManagerURL: 'https://manager.com.au'
  }

  if (env == 'dev') {

  } 
  else if (env == 'e2e') {

  }

  return config;

}
```

This is the only file I have for environments.  I am unsure as to how can I run my tests in multiple environments.

Do I need to create a new `karate.config.<env>.js` file (as per the docs) to run my tests in a new environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only this one file. Now the `config` JSON returned has some default values set. What you can do now is have different values for `e2e`, for example:

```
else if (env == 'e2e') {
  config.internalGateway = 'https://gateway-e2e.com.au';
}
```

And when you run your tests, you switch environments on the command-line. This is just setting a [Java System Property](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/java-system-properties/). There are many other ways to do this:

```
mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=e2e"
```

All this is explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#switching-the-environment

Comment: Cool!! But if i want to run my tests on my local from eclipse itself, then what should i do ?

Comment: @SnehaShukla clearly you did not even bother to read the link I provided. try again please.

Comment: I have read it before asking the question sir. And that's where i got confused as  to what's the logic with "karate.config.dir" . Running through command line is not what i am worried about.

Comment: My doubt was actually about "karate.config.dir" file

Comment: @SnehaShukla which I answered. you only need `karate-config.js` please forget about `karate.config.dir` it is for advanced users. and you did NOT read the link in my answer. "how to run in eclipse" is homework for you. all the best :)

Comment: I have already set different variables for different environment in the environment file. I am just not sure how to instruct karate as to run "e2e" or "dev" before starting the tes

Comment: It worked!! It was such a stupid question. Sorry for being the most annoying student.